# Fatal error: Call to a member function append()

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to create a custom module (study purpose) to show the payment details of a particular user.

I am stuck in between blocks and layouts and getting an error like:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function append()

```
<?php
class PITS_Pitsnews_PaymentController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {

    protected function _getSession() {
        return Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
    }

    public function indexAction() {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');
        $session = $this->_getSession();
        if (!$this->_getSession()->isLoggedIn()) {
            $this->_redirect('customer/account/login/');
            return;
        }
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('pitsnews')->append(
            $this->getLayout()->createBlock('pitsnews/pitsnews')
        );
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('pitsnews/pitsnews')->assign('data', $data);
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

Comment: As you can read from the error, you are calling out to a non-existing function append.

Comment: `$this->getLayout()->getBlock('pitsnews')` is returning something that is not an object. Please show `var_dump($this->getLayout()->getBlock('pitsnews'));`

Comment: @DaveRandom: Ys i debugged this and seems like i have got the solutions for this. I think i had missed a point here.Forget add the layout in the markup file . `<pitsnews_payment_index> <reference name="content"> <block type="pitsnews/pitsnews" name="pitsnews" block_id="pitsnews" template="pitsnews/pitsnews.phtml" /> </reference> </pitsnews_payment_index>`

Comment: @DaveRandom:i hav one more doubt . `$count = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getSummaryCount();` This code returns the total number of items in the cart . How can i pass this variable '$count' to the view section, Eg if we are on zend framework we have some thing like this `$this->view->var1 = "testing var1 ";` to pass the variable to view side . In magento how can i pass valies to frontend .

Answer (score 0):

seems like

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('pitsnews')
```

is not a layout object here, so verify:

- if your layout markup injects the block to this dispatcher
- if you don't have layout file in your extension then you need to create this block on the fly before calling any methods on it

Comment: Many thanks fr your quick reply.This means that i need add something like this `<pitsnews_payment_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="pitsnews/pitsnews" name="pitsnews"  block_id="pitsnews"  template="pitsnews/pitsnews.phtml" />
        </reference> 
    </pitsnews_payment_index>` to solve this issue rt ??

Comment: :i hav one more doubt . `$count = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getSummaryCount();` This code returns the total number of items in the cart . How can i pass this variable '$count' to  the view section, Eg if we are on zend framework we have some thing like this `$this->view->var1 = "testing var1 ";` to pass the variable to view side . In magento how can i pass valies to frontend .

Comment: you can set any variable to your block `$blockObject()->setWhatever('value');` and on the view you can `$this->getWhatever();` or use the helper directly on your view